# Sql server - dynamically change all foreign key constraints Update_Rule

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, constraints

I am trying to go over all the foreign key constraints with `UPDATE_RULE` set to `'NO ACTION'` in the database, and change that rule to `'CASCADE'`.
So, I know I should first drop that constraint and re-add it.

In order to do that, I tried the following query to get all the relevant constraints, and then iterating each row and building a dynamic sql query which will drop the constraint, and will re-add it just with a different `UPDATE_RULE` value.

However, in order to add the constraint, I need the table name of where the primary key is defined, and I don't have it in my query. I only have the table name where the foreign key is:

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS AS RC
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.table_constraints AS CU
  ON CU.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = RC.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG
  AND CU.CONSTRAINT_NAME = RC.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE UPDATE_RULE = 'NO ACTION'
```

Any suggestions of how to do it?
I only need to change the constraint `UPDATE_RULE` value.

Answer (score 1):

Answer was found here:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31720/find-the-foreign-keys-associated-with-a-given-primary-key

```
SELECT
o1.name AS FK_table,
c1.name AS FK_column,
fk.name AS FK_name,
o2.name AS PK_table,
c2.name AS PK_column,
pk.name AS PK_name,
fk.delete_referential_action_desc AS Delete_Action,
fk.update_referential_action_desc AS Update_Action
FROM sys.objects o1
INNER JOIN sys.foreign_keys fk
    ON o1.object_id = fk.parent_object_id
INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
    ON fk.object_id = fkc.constraint_object_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns c1
    ON fkc.parent_object_id = c1.object_id
    AND fkc.parent_column_id = c1.column_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns c2
    ON fkc.referenced_object_id = c2.object_id
    AND fkc.referenced_column_id = c2.column_id
INNER JOIN sys.objects o2
    ON fk.referenced_object_id = o2.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.key_constraints pk
    ON fk.referenced_object_id = pk.parent_object_id
    AND fk.key_index_id = pk.unique_index_id
ORDER BY o1.name, o2.name, fkc.constraint_column_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @fk_table NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @fk_column NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @fk_name NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @pk_table NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @pk_column NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @pk_name NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @deleteAction NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @updateAction NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE relationsCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT
o1.name AS FK_table,
c1.name AS FK_column,
fk.name AS FK_name,
o2.name AS PK_table,
c2.name AS PK_column,
pk.name AS PK_name,
fk.delete_referential_action_desc AS Delete_Action,
fk.update_referential_action_desc AS Update_Action
FROM sys.objects o1
INNER JOIN sys.foreign_keys fk
    ON o1.object_id = fk.parent_object_id
INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
    ON fk.object_id = fkc.constraint_object_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns c1
    ON fkc.parent_object_id = c1.object_id
    AND fkc.parent_column_id = c1.column_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns c2
    ON fkc.referenced_object_id = c2.object_id
    AND fkc.referenced_column_id = c2.column_id
INNER JOIN sys.objects o2
    ON fk.referenced_object_id = o2.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.key_constraints pk
    ON fk.referenced_object_id = pk.parent_object_id
    AND fk.key_index_id = pk.unique_index_id
Where fk.update_referential_action_desc = 'NO_ACTION'
ORDER BY o1.name, o2.name, fkc.constraint_column_id

OPEN relationsCursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM relationsCursor INTO @fk_table, @fk_column,@fk_name,@pk_table,@pk_column,@pk_name,@deleteAction,@updateAction;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @sql = 'ALTER TABLE [' + @fk_table + '] DROP CONSTRAINT [' + @fk_name+']';
    print @sql;
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

    SET @sql = 'ALTER TABLE [' + @fk_table + '] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [' + @fk_name +'] FOREIGN KEY (['+ @fk_column  +']) REFERENCES ['+@pk_table+'] (['+@pk_column+']) ON UPDATE CASCADE';
    print @sql;

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
    FETCH NEXT FROM relationsCursor INTO @fk_table, @fk_column,@fk_name,@pk_table,@pk_column,@pk_name,@deleteAction,@updateAction;
END

CLOSE relationsCursor;
DEALLOCATE relationsCursor;
```

but when you change NO ACTION relations to CASCADE it may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths , I wrote similar code to convert CASCADE relations to NO ACTION on DELETE rule to ensure no unwanted records are deleted.